# Best way to make a UITextField "appear"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitextfield

I'd like a `UITextField` to appear when a button is pressed. Unfortunately, I can't hide it in Interface Builder and then set the hidden property to `NO` later because "ibtool fails with exit code 5" if you try to hide a `UITextField`.

I'll try to do this in code but wondering if I may be missing something or making a grave UI error by attempting to do something like this? Or maybe it's just a bug?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't set it to hidden in IB, you can do it programatically, with `field.hidden = YES;` in your viewController's `viewDidLoad` method. Then just set it back to `NO` in the button's target action.

Answer (score 1):

weird, but you could just add it programmatically, and show it with some opacity animation.

Answer (score 1):

Or, simply set its `alpha` to 0.0. You can even really easily animate the change and it'll look really good.

Comment: This does appear to be more elegant. Animating the HIDDEN property doesn't seem to work. It's all or nothing. so using a combo of HIDDEN and Alpha keeps the keeps it hidden and prevents it from responding to touches until it's activated. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding a `UITextField` in IB and checking the `hidden` box, and got no crash.  Of course, I'm running the 3.0 beta SDK, so it may be a bug that was fixed there.  Either way, though, you should be able to just mark it as hidden and then in code set `hidden = NO`.  I'm not sure why it's not working for you without more information.

Comment: I tried it with the 2.2 SDK and got the same result, so yes, perhaps it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, looks like a bug, but a possible simple workaround is to simply make it empty, i.e. give it no string value in `IB`, and set that string value (via `NSLocalizedString()` of course) when you want it to 'appear'.